# simple GET request in mocha timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, mocha.js

I have the following code

```
const https = require("https");

it("wait for some result", function (done) {
  this.timeout(15000);
  const options = {
    hostname: "httpbin.org",
    path: "/get",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "bearer ",
    },
  };
  https.get(options, (resp) => {
    let data = "";
    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
      console.log(data);
    });
    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on("end", () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
    });

    resp.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
    done();
  });
});
```

this returns:

1. should respond with redirect on post:
   Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

I am trying to make this asynchronous because of mocha, which is why I am using callback. I am even waiting 15000 instead of the default 2000ms.

this code normally works, only fails with mocha.
Not sure how to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried put `done` in `resp.on("end")` callback?

Comment: @Yevhenii yes I get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

try to add `.end()` on your request object

```js
  const req = https.get(options, (resp) => {
    let data = "";
    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
      console.log(data);
    });
    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on("end", () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
      done();
    });

    resp.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
  });
  req.end()
```